# Google Cloud Platform mount pvc to instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, mount

I am testing a Postgresql backup process for kubernetes. My cluster is now crashing (CrashLoopBackOff) and I know exactly what to do to fix it, but I need to access the PVC it's running on. I am more experienced with AWS and haven't used GCP much. I quickly created a "rescue" VM and I would like to mount the pvc-xxxx to the VM (debian linux) and fix the data on the volume.

How do I mount the PVC on the linux instance? I have been googling about and found the following command:

```
gcloud compute instances attach-disk instance-1 --disk pvc-xxxxxxx
```

but that doesn't work because I am trying to attach a PVC instead of a disk (I am guessing).
Is there a way I can "attach-pvc" a PVC to a running instance?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This case is exactly described by Google in its [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/persistent-volumes).

> **Using preexisting persistent disks as PersistentVolumes**
>
> Dynamically provisioned PersistentVolume resources are empty when they
> are created. If you have an existing Compute Engine persistent disk
> populated with data, you can introduce it to your cluster by manually
> creating a corresponding PersistentVolume resource. The persistent
> disk must be in the same zone as the cluster nodes.

If you follow [this](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/persistent-volumes/preexisting-pd) step-by-step guide I am sure you will get it working. However, it is a little more than one command. I think it is the last part of this template that you are interested in:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv-statefulset-demo-1
spec:
  storageClassName: "example-storageclass"
  capacity:
    storage: 100Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  claimRef:
    namespace: default
    name: www-web-1
  gcePersistentDisk:
    pdName: pd-one
    fsType: ext4
```